# Conectar PHP a SQL Server 2008 usando una clase

Tags: php

alguien me sabría decir porque no me funciona este código? Lo he visto en otro ejemplo aquí y dice que le funciona.

```
<?php
    class Conexion{
        private $cn;
        public function __construct(){
        $serverName = "localhost";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"gestor", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"egestion", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
        $this->cn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        }
        public function getConecta(){
            return $this->cn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Esta es la otra pagina php a la que hace referencia.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
        <?php
 class Conexion{}
        $cn = new Conexion;
        ?>
```

Aqui agrego usuario

```
php<?
        class Usuario { 
            public function agregarUsuario(){
                $cn = new Conexion;
            if(isset($_POST['insert'])){
                $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
                $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
                $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
                $email = $_POST['email'];

                $insertar = "INSERT INTO  t_usuarios(nombre, apellidos, password, email)VALUES('$nombre', 'apellidos', '$password', '$email')";

                $ejecutar = sqlsrv_query($cn->getConecta(), $insertar);

                if($ejecutar){
                    echo "<h3>Insertado correctamente</h3>";
                }
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

A ver si alguien se le ocurre algo de porque no me funciona, llevo días con esto.
Gracias

He agregado eso a ver si me devuelve algun error pero nada sigue la pantalla en blanco.

```
<?php
    class Conexion{
        private $cn;
        public function __construct(){
        $serverName = "localhost";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"gestor", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"egestion", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
        $this->cn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        }
        if($cn === FALSE){
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
        }
        public function getConecta(){
            return $this->cn;
        }
    }
?>
```

He modificado el codigo para ver que me error me da el if pero sigue la pantalla en blanco.

```
<?php
    class Conexion{
        private $cn;
        public function __construct(){
        $serverName = "localhost";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"gestor", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"egestion", "CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
        $this->cn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
            if($cn === FALSE){
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
            }
        }

        public function getConecta(){
            return $this->cn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Que error obtienes?

Comment: No me sale ningún error, simplemente se queda la pantalla en blanco. si le quito la clase si me conecta. El problema es la clase que no me conecta.

Comment: Y estás haciendo la instancia de dicha clase? Para que con el objeto accedas al método de conexión y ahí nos diga el posible error

Comment: despues tengo esto que no me da error, pero no trae los datos. Me salen los campos vacios.

Comment: BetaM ya he puesto mas codigo a ver si así lo ves mejor. Gracias

Comment: Agrega la linea if($cn === FALSE){ die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));} después de crear la instancia de la conexión a ver si te devuelve algún error.

Comment: Ok, la pantalla en blanco. Y en los logs sale algo?

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, donde puedo ver los logs?

Comment: En el código no se ve dónde creas la instancia de la clase `Usuario` y llamas sus métodos para que funcione. Por otra parte, en el `if` que pusiste para verificar los errores, no es correcto, ese `if` por lógica, debería estar dentro del constructor, lo tienes fuera de todas las funciones de la clase, y por tanto dará error. Es importante que tengas claro una cosa: las clases son como modelos o moldes que usarás cada vez que necesites trabajar con instancias de ese objeto. En este caso, para trabajar con un `Usuario` debes creas una instancia de esa clase e invocar sus métodos.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano creo que me falta mucho que aprender porque no he entendido muy bien lo que me has querido decir. La verdad que estoy muy perdido no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

No comprendo porque sigo sin poderme conectar. He probado con este codigo que he visto en la web de Microsoft y no me conecta. Si quito toda la parte de function y solo dejo la parte del codigo de la conexion si me conecta pero al ponerle un function o un class ya se me queda la pantalla en blanco. Alguien puede ayudarme por favor.

```
<?php 
     function OpenConnection()  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            $serverName = "localhost";  
            $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"gestor",  
                "Uid"=>"s", "PWD"=>"egestion");  
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);  
            if($conn == false);
                die(FormatErrors(sqlsrv_errors()));  
        }  
        catch(Exception $e)  
        {  
            echo("Error!");  
        }  
    }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Solo como pregunta quizá ilógica, pero ¿ya tienes instalados los drives de SQL Server para PHP?

Comment: Si, como he comentado si no le pongo ni class ni function y solo pongo el código de conexión si me conecta

Comment: ¿Has intentado colocar en lugar de localhost la IP de tu PC?

Comment: Si tambien, y pongo mal el usuario para provocar un fallo de conexion y que me salte el error y nada, pantalla en blanco

Comment: Acabo de colocar una respuesta que es la forma que utilizo actualmente y me funciona sin problemas, ojala te sirva. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer la conexión de esta forma (es la que a mi me funciona sin problemas):

```
<?php

function conexion(){

$serverName = "tu servidor";
$connectionInfo = array( "UID" => "usuario", "PWD" => "contraseña", "Database" => "DB", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if(!$conn) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }

return $conn;
}
?>
```

Luego utilizas la conexión de esta forma:

```
$conn = conexion();

if($conn === FALSE){
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}
```

Como te decía a mi me funciona y he utilizado este mismo método para SQL Server 2008 R2 hasta 2019. Espero te sirva, suerte.

Comment: he copiado la primera parte de tu código en una pagina php, tal y como me lo has mandado, solo he cambiado "tu servidor" por "localhost" el resto lo he dejado igual queriendo para que no pueda conectar y me salte un error. Después corro la pagina php en el navegador y me sale la pagina en blanco............... POR QUE??

Comment: ¿No habrás desactivado por casualidad los warnings de PHP? solo como posible "por que" por favor verificar que en tu archivo php.ini display_errors este en on.

Comment: display_errors
   Default Value: On
   Development Value: On
   Production Value: On

Comment: Que versión de PHP usas?

Comment: Uso PHP 7, he conseguido conectar con la bd, pero ahora no me trae los registros

Comment: Edita la pregunta por favor con el nuevo escenario para poder tener un mejor panorama de que ocurre ahora